# Kamailio TLS connection not establishing on TLS socket 5061

Tags: openssl, debian, microsoft-teams, kamailio

I am trying to setup MS Teams Direct Routing with Kamailio version: kamailio 5.6.5 (x86_64/linux).I have setup a domain and get users registered with it.I have done all the configs following this tutorial https://skalatan.de/en/blog/kamailio-sbc-teams

but when I checked My TLS is not coming up

sudo netstat -tulpn | grep kamailio

udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:50600.0.0.0:* 1858/kamailio

It's listening on 5060 but not on tls.

my certificate works for my https but kamailio unable to listen on 5061.
I checked the configs and they are fine followed other patterns but still not able to get kamailio listen on tls 5061.

Comment: have you added second listen directive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

1. correct certificates in tls.cfg
2. listen directive

Like this:

```
listen=tls:IPADDRESS:5061
```

or

```
listen=tls:PRIVATEIP:5061 advertise PUBLICIP:5061
```

Most of manuals just not write last one, no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

tls: 172.31.19.8:5061 advertise abcsbc.com:5061

It's now listening on tls port but now I get the below errors.

This is the error when sending options packet to Microsoft.

ERROR: tls [tls_server.c:1319]: tls_h_read_f(): protocol level error

ERROR: tls [tls_util.h:49]: tls_err_ret(): TLS write:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (sni: unknown)
ERROR: tls [tls_server.c:1323]: tls_h_read_f(): src addr: 52.114.132.46:5061
ERROR: tls [tls_server.c:1326]: tls_h_read_f(): dst addr: 172.31.19.8:0
ERROR:  [core/tcp_read.c:1499]: tcp_read_req(): ERROR: tcp_read_req: error reading - c: 0x7fde1e939fd8 r: 0x7fde1e93a100 (-1)
ERROR: tls [tls_server.c:1319]: tls_h_read_f(): protocol level error
ERROR: tls [tls_util.h:49]: tls_err_ret(): TLS write:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (sni: unknown)

These are my configs

kamailio.cfg
listen=tls:172.31.19.8:5061 advertise abcsbc.com:5061

```
[server:default]
method = TLSv1.2+
verify_certificate = yes
require_certificate = no
private_key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/privkey.pem
certificate = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/fullchain.pem
server_name = abc.com
server_id = abc.com
ca_list = /etc/kamailio/ca_list.pem
[client:default]
method = TLSv1.2+
verify_certificate = yes
require_certificate = yes
private_key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/privkey.pem
certificate = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/fullchain.pem
ca_list = /etc/kamailio/ca_list.pem
```

Comment: Now you need ensure teams know about your certificate(actually you should use team's clients set of certificates). Anyway, it is not answer for this question. Debug is offtopic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the tls sni issue with this setting finally.

```
[server:default]
method = TLSv1.2+
verify_certificate = yes
require_certificate = yes
private_key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/privkey.pem
certificate = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/fullchain.pem
ca_list = /etc/kamailio/ca_list.pem
#ca_list = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/cert.pem


[server:172.31.19.8:5061]
method = TLSv1.2+
verify_certificate = yes
require_certificate = yes
private_key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/privkey.pem
certificate = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/fullchain.pem
ca_list = /etc/kamailio/ca_list.pem
server_name = localhost


[client:default]
method = TLSv1.2+
verify_certificate = no
require_certificate = no
server_name = abcsbc.com

[client:172.31.19.8:5061]
method = TLSv1.2+
verify_certificate = yes
require_certificate = yes
private_key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/privkey.pem
certificate = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/fullchain.pem
ca_list = /etc/kamailio/ca_list.pem
server_name = localhost
server_id = localhost


#private_key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/privkey.pem
#certificate = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/fullchain.pem
#ca_list = /etc/kamailio/ca_list.pem
#ca_list = /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcsbc.com/cert.pem
But now the thing to worry is my dispatcher flag goes from AX to IP. :(

kamcmd dispatcher.list | egrep "URI|FLAGS"
URI: sip:sip.pstnhub.microsoft.com:5061;transport=tls
FLAGS: IP
URI: sip:sip2.pstnhub.microsoft.com:5061;transport=tls
FLAGS: IP
URI: sip:sip3.pstnhub.microsoft.com:5061;transport=tls
FLAGS: IP
```

now getting dispatcher in IP state why ?